# Вставить пробелы в строку по известным индексам

Tags: python, index

У меня есть строка и я кодом сохраняю индексы в список. Например у меня была такая строка

```
str_old = "sdf dsf hgfh"
```

И получился такой список хранящий индекс где был пробел

```
index_prob = [3, 7]
```

Далее у меня в строке удаляются лишние пробелы и я получаю такую строку

```
str_new = "sdfdsfhgfh"
```

Теперь в такую же строку по длине(там будут другие символы, но для примера оставим эту) должны вставиться пробелы из списка. У меня были попытки со срезами но это не работает так как надо. Может есть другой способ?

```
encrypt2 = ""
k = 0
pov = 0
if(len(index_prob) > 0):
while( k < len(index_prob)):
    if k == 0:
        encrypt2 += str_new[ : index_prob[k]] + " "
        print(encrypt2)
    elif k == len(index_prob) - 1:
        encrypt2 += str_new[index_prob[k] - k : ]
        print(encrypt2)
    else:
        encrypt2 += str_new[len(encrypt2) - 1 : index_prob[k] - 1] + " "
        print(encrypt2)
    k += 1
print(encrypt2)
```

Такой вопрос. Как мне вставить пробелы в строку, по индексам хранящимся в списке. Это так же должно работать когда есть много пробелов. Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
str = "sdf   dsf  hgfh"
sdfdsfhgfh
[3, 4, 5, 9, 10]
```

Comment: `s = list(s)
for i in arr:s.insert(i, ' ')
s=''.join(s)`

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы удалить в списке пробелы, можно сделать так:

```py
a = "ab cd ef gh"
b = a.split()
b = "".join(b)
print(b)
```

`split("<symbol>")` нужен чтобы разделить на данный символ, оставьте пустым чтобы делить на пробелы.
`"<symbol>".join(<list>)` нужен чтобы добавить все части символом. Оставьте пустым если не надо что-то добавлять внутри каждого элемента.

Comment: Это не ответ на заданный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то можно предложить что-то такое

```py
string = "sdf   dsf  hgfh"
spaces_idx = [i for i in range(len(string)) if string[i] == ' ']

no_space_string = string.replace(' ', '')

alter_string_orig = 'alopjokgwe'

alter_string_symbols = [*alter_string_orig]

while spaces_idx:
    alter_string_symbols.insert(
        spaces_idx.pop(0),
        ' '
    )

alter_string_w_spaces = ''.join(alter_string_symbols)

print(string, alter_string_w_spaces, sep='\n')
```

Вывод:

```latex
sdf   dsf  hgfh
alo   pjo  kgwe
```

Answer (score 0):

`slices(indices)` выдаёт последовательность сегментов индексов. Для списка `[3, 7]` получатся три сегмента `[0:3]`, `[3:6]`, `[6:]`.

`insert_spaces(s, indices)` разрезает строку на куски и соединяет их через пробел. Готово за линейное время.

```
def slices(indices):
    prev_k = 0
    for i, j in enumerate(indices):
        k = j - i
        yield slice(prev_k, k)
        prev_k = k
    yield slice(prev_k, None)


def insert_spaces(s, indices):
    return ' '.join(s[sl] for sl in slices(indices))


print(insert_spaces('sdfdsfhgfh', [3, 7]))
```

> ```
> $ python insert-spaces.py
> sdf dsf hgfh
> ```